# Errors for RDFa in my HTML example

Tags: html, validation, rdfa

I am new to programming and I'm working on writing RDFa in HTML. I know I'm close, but I've not getting validated at [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/). I'm wondering if anyone with more experience may be able to identify my shortcomings.

SO = schema.org
DC - Dublin Core
GL - GoodLaPhonso (my own schema and not a real website yet)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RDFa in HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>
<div vocab="http://schema.org/">
div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="product">
<a property="brand"=SO:brand="Coldwater Creek"</span></a>, 
<div>
Category: <span property="category">Moose</span>
</div>
<div>
 Color: <span property="color">Brass</span> 
</div>
<div>
Date Created: <span property="dateCreated">1996</span> 
 </div>
 <div>
 Image: <span property="image">Object</span>
 </div>
 <div>
 Location Created: <span property="locationCreated">Unknown</span>
</div>
<div>
<div vocab="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator">
div vocab="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator" typeof="creator">
Creator: <a property="creator">Unknown</a> 
</div>
<div>
<div vocab="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/description">
div vocab="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/description"  t
typeof="description">
Description: <a property="description">1996 brass moose ornament from Coldwater Creek.</a>
</div>
<div>
<div vocab="http://goodlaphonso.org">
div vocab="http://goodlaphonso.org" typeof=“ID">
Ornament ID: <a property=“ornamentid”>0</a>
</div>
<div>
Market Value: <a property=“marketValue">25 dollars</a>
</div>
<div>
Size:<span property=“size”>4 inches</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You have several HTML errors.

Missing `<` (but some of these lines seem to be duplicated):

```html
div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="product">

div vocab="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator" typeof="creator">

div vocab="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/description"  t
typeof="description">

div vocab="http://goodlaphonso.org" typeof=“ID">
```

Wrong quotation marks (`“` instead of `"`):

```html
typeof=“ID"

property=“ornamentid”

property=“marketValue"

property=“size”
```

Wrong attributes:

```html
=SO:brand="Coldwater Creek"

t
```

Closing `span` tag without opening tag:

```html
 <a property="brand"=SO:brand="Coldwater Creek"</span></a>
```

#### About your RDFa

URIs are case-sensitive. So it has to be `Product`, not `product`.

As you are using multiple vocabularies, you may find it easier to use one `prefix` (e.g., on the `body` element) instead of several `vocab` attributes. [See an example.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/67264/17633) This would also allow you to mix vocabularies for the same content.

It’s typically not useful to provide property values like "Unknown". If the `locationCreated` or the `creator` is unknow, omit the property. Otherwise the creator and the location would be named "Unknown".